# Apache Solr 8.5.2: Solr not starting due to ClassNotFoundException

Tags: solr

I am trying to run Solr 8.5.2 in my local. When starting, I am getting the following error :

```
INFO  - 2021-06-02 06:58:51.080; [   x:blrla00144_search] org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig; 
Using Lucene MatchVersion: 8.5.2
WARN  - 2021-06-02 06:58:51.092; [   ] org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.BaseHolder; 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.servlet.ZookeeperInfoServlet
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:450)
```

> I searched for its reference on google and found it as part of
> Solr-Core-4.1.  When I tried search the file in Solr-Core-8.5.2, it
> does not list in jar.

If I manually add solr-core-4.1, then it throws incompatibility exception.

What is the issue and how can I solve it ? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with web.xml. It had servlet entries for ZookeeperInfoServlet. Removing those, fixed the issue.